# Replace part of columns string value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column with values like `/i/t/item_xxl_12063874_18123233.jpg`. I need a formula to get a string value `item_xxl_12063874_18123233.jpg`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code?

Comment: Thanks @OrkhanAlikhanov. I don't know how to write this sort of formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's always to remove the first 5 characters, simply

```
=MID(A1, 6, 9999)
```

BUT if it is about retrieving what is after the last `/`, with a random amount of characters before it, then it is a little more tricky:

```
 =TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "/", REPT(" ", 300)), 300))
```

Comment: Thanks A.S.H. Your first formula works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to find the text "item" as follows:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("item",A1,1),LEN(A1))
```

you can change the text you search for as necessary and it does not matter how many are before the text you search for as long as it only occurs once.